# Is solving $ \frac {d^2y}{dx^2} -y = x^2\sin(3x) $ using variation of parameters possible?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My attempts at it failed at resolving the imaginary part of the equation after substituting $e^{3ix}$ for $\sin(3x)$.

Comment: Thanks, I  meant to ask if using variation of parameters was possible. Will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Let's start by finding the complementary solution.
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}-y=0$$
We make the ansatz $y=e^{\lambda x}$ to obtain the characteristic equation:
$$\lambda^2-1=0$$
$$\lambda=\pm 1$$
This implies that the complementary solution is:
$$y_c(x)=c_1 e^{-x}+c_2 e^x$$
The basis solutions are $e^{-x}$ and $e^{x}$. Thus, the Wronskian is:
$$W(x)=\begin{vmatrix} e^{-x} & e^{x} \\ -e^{-x} & e^x \end{vmatrix}=2$$
The particular solution will thus be given by:
$$y_p(x)=v_1(x) e^{-x}+v_2(x) e^x$$
Where:
$$v_1(x)=-\int \frac{f(x)\cdot e^{x}}{W(x)}~dx=-\int \frac{x^2\sin(3x)\cdot e^{x}}{2}~dx$$
And:
$$v_2(x)=\int \frac{f(x)\cdot e^{-x}}{W(x)}~dx=\int \frac{x^2\sin(3x)\cdot e^{-x}}{2}~dx$$
Can you continue?

Comment: I think so, this seems doable.  I was stuck at accurately writing down $\ y_p $   resolving the terms of $\  v_1 $ and $\ v_2 $ and was completely off the mark.  Thanks.